# Errno 61: Connection refused error when trying to connect to python server

Tags: python, sockets

I've recently been trying to experiment with creating simple online multiplayer games with python's socket module. I made a first draft of a server and client program, and though they work perfectly when I run them both from the same computer, my attempts to connect the client when running on another computer results in the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Admins2-Admins_In_Space/Downloads/gameclient.py", line 22, in <module>
    client.connect((host,port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

(both computers are connected to the same router, so it isn't a problem there.) The code for the server is

```
import socket, threading

class dataBase():
    "A class to store all playerdata"
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

class client():
    "handles an individual client"

    def __init__(self,ip,port,value,dataBase):
        self.mainThread = threading.Thread(None,self.run)
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.value = value
        self.dataBase = dataBase
        print('New connection with' + ip)
        self.mainThread.start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
            if data != None:
                exec('data = ' + data)
                self.dataBase[self.value] = data
                data = self.dataBase
                message = []
                for d in range(len(data)):
                    if d == value:
                        continue
                    message.append(data[d])
                if message != []:
                    conn.send(str(message).encode())
            else:
                self.conn.close()
                break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = []
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 1234
    value = 0
    threads = []

    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.bind((host,port))

    while True:
        sock.listen(5)
        (conn,(ip,port)) = sock.accept()
        newThread = client(ip,port,value,data)
        data.append(())
        threads.append(newThread)
        value += 1

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

and here's the client, up to line 22

```
import pygame, socket, sys
from pygame.locals import *

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 1234

up = False
down = False
left = False
right = False
x = 0
y = 0
data = None

if __name__ == '__main__':

    pygame.init()
    window = pygame.display.set_mode((1250,1000), 0, 32)
    pygame.display.set_caption('client test')

    client = socket.socket()
    client.connect((host,port))
```

I've been running the server from a raspberry pi 3 model b with the latest version of raspbian, and the failed client tests have been running on various macs.

Answer (score 0):

> though they work perfectly when I run them both from the same computer, my attempts to connect the client when running on another computer results in the following error …

In the client, you still have `host = '127.0.0.1'` (i. e. *localhost*), but if you want to connect to a server *on another computer*, you have to set `host` to that computer's address. And in the server, you should change `host = '127.0.0.1'` to `host = '0.0.0.0'`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. The ip address programmed into the server and client right now is the address of the server, though.

Comment: It's a bit unfortunate then that you didn't show the code as it is _right now_.

Comment: The suggestion failed, so the code is still the same.